# Videoplayer doesn't play video in splah screen

Tags: android, video, splash-screen, android-video-player

I have a splahs screen in my application and i am playing a video on that activity. But in some Android versions ( i mean old ) the video doesnt play. i dont know what to do..

here is some of my code

```
 public void PlayVideo(){
    try{             
            videoPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.afad_splash_ip4));
            videoPlayer.prepare();
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }
    try {
          AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("splash.mp4");             
          videoPlayer.reset();           
          videoPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());              
          videoPlayer.prepare();          
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
            {
              try
              {                   
               Log.v("video ", "catch");
               videoPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
               videoPlayer.setVolume(0f, 0f);
               videoPlayer.start();
               videoPlayer.setLooping(false);                   
               videoPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                public  void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(VideoSplash.this,ListActivity.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_top,R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
                    finish();
                    }
                });
              }
              catch (Exception e)
                 {      //TODO
                     //Burada Video yerine resim koymalısın
                     //Kimi cihazlarda video oynamayabilir
                  Log.v("resim", "catch");
                  //Thats where i want to put a pic as a backgroun to my SurfaceView. and make it wait 10 secs
                 // videoSurface.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.son_frame));
                  }
                //TODO
            //Burada Video yerine resim koymalısın
            //Kimi cihazlarda video oynamayabilir               

            }                      


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code will help you

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity implements OnErrorListener,
OnPreparedListener {

LoadAsyncTask video_async_task;

private VideoView  mVideoView

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

super.onCreate(icicle); 
setContentView(R.layout.video);
mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.mysurfaceview);
mVideoView.setMediaController(myctrl);


mVideoView.requestFocus();

video_async_task = new LoadAsyncTask();
video_async_task.execute();

}

private class LoadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 

mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));

}


}
```